# Google oAuth request

Tags: c++, curl, oauth, google-api, google-calendar-api

I try to add an event in my calendar by an installed application.
The problem: I didn't get the success-code to change for an access token.

My request seems like following:

```
accounts.google.com:80/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https:%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&client_id=73561***.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

If i send this request at the browser it works. Like the [example](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?%20scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&%20redirect_uri=urn%3aietf%3awg%3aoauth:2.0%3aoob&%20response_type=code&%20client_id=812741506391-h38jh0j4fv0ce1krdkiq0hfvt6n5amrf.apps.googleusercontent.com).
 But i wanted my application to do everything for me. That means, that the User only give his login dates and he is able to add as an example an event. Without giving the agreement. Well, if my application send the same request i get an answer: "moved temporarily". But i need the key (success code) from the title bar.

I should add, that i use c++ so i can't use the Google Api. Therefore, i use cURL to send my request.

Anyone able to help me?

Comment: Please share the curl request you are using.